# Unable to block weekends from the Jquery Datepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I used the following script from here

[JQUERY](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)

Select `Extensions` to check for the minimal pages in that link i posted

But i am unable to block the week ends if i write as he specified so can any one tell why this is what i have done

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        @import "css/jquery.datepick.css";
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $('#txtPaymentDate').datepick({
                onDate: $.datepick.noWeekends, showTrigger: '#calImg'
            });
        });
```

`<asp:TextBox ID="txtPaymentDate" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtPaymentDate_TextChanged"
                        Width="136px"></asp:TextBox>`
`<div style="display: none;">
                        <img id="calImg" src="images/calendar.gif" alt="Popup" class="trigger" />
                    </div>`

I am going to have a calendar with week ends selectable can any one tell what's wrong i am doing

Comment: I suspect whether you need to use `beforeShowDay` for that

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495284/jquery-tools-disable-weekend-days

Comment: Actually as per the documentation given in that page did not specify that `beforeshowday` and if you look at the script he written it is same but still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the Extensions tab, it says:

> The **jquery.datepick.ext.js** module provides additional functionality to extend the datepicker

(emphasis added).

And looking in the downloads, there does appear to be a file of that name included. But you're only using `jquery.datepick.js`

So try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.datepick.ext.js"></script>
```